Openlayers: Make zoom work on SVG image layer
I'm trying to render a non-georeferenced SVG layer using OpenLayers. (I'll also try tackling having a georeferenced SVG layer as well at a later point). As you can see, I'm using an inline base64 encoded SVG.
However, I'm struggling to make the zoom part work well.
This is the relevant bit (some variables between the parentheses are inserted in the final code).
What exactly am I missing? Probably something resolution related; as it seems the aspect ratio is what is failing for me?
Does anyone have a working example?
I just want the zoom to work properly.
new ol.layer.Image({
    opacity: {$fOpacity},
    visible: {$sVisibility},
    minZoom: {$fMinZoom},
    maxZoom: {$fMaxZoom},
    source: new ol.source.Image({
        projection: imageProjection_{$oSource->GetKey()},
        extent: imageExtent_{$oSource->GetKey()},
        loader: (extent, resolution, pixelRatio) => {
            

            const ratio = 1;

            retExtent = ol.source.Image.getRequestExtent(extent, resolution, pixelRatio, ratio);

            const image = new Image()
            // const svgViewBox = '#svgView(viewBox(0,0,{$iWidthPx},{$iHeightPx}))';

            const fWidth = {$iWidthPx};
            const fHeight = {$iHeightPx};
            const fOffsetX = fWidth / 2;
            const fOffsetY = fHeight / 2;

            const svgViewBox = '#svgView(viewBox(' +
                + (retExtent[0] + fOffsetX)
                + ',' 
                + (retExtent[1] + fOffsetY)
                + ',' 
                + (retExtent[2] + fOffsetX)
                + ',' 
                + (retExtent[3] + fOffsetY)
                + '))';

            console.log(svgViewBox);

            image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,{$sEncodedSVG}' + svgViewBox;

            return { image, retExtent, pixelRatio };
        }
    })
})


Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. We're not Google.

Note than SVGs need width and height attributes to work consistently (or work at all with Firefox) when drawn to canvas.  If you have a viewBox you should also set preserveAspectRatio="none" if the image needs scaling.
You could consider using a custom layer as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/svg-layer.html
or use the ImageStatic equivalent of https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image-svg.html as in the code below


<html>
<head>
  <style>
    html, body, .map {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.12.1/proj4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v10.2.1/dist/ol.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v10.2.1/ol.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <script>

proj4.defs(
  'EPSG:27700',
  '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 ' +
    '+x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy ' +
    '+towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 ' +
    '+units=m +no_defs'
);
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

const imageExtent = [0, 0, 700000, 1300000];

const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    }),
    new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.Image({
        loader: ol.source.static.createLoader({
          url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/British_National_Grid.svg',
          crossOrigin: '',
          imageExtent: imageExtent,
          load: ol.Image.load,
        }),
        projection: 'EPSG:27700',
      }),
    }),
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.extent.getCenter(imageExtent),
    zoom: 4,
    projection: 'EPSG:27700',
  }),
});

  </script>
</body>

</html>



